# If select policy_ID INTO VPOLICYID FROM POLICY T WHERE ETC... RETURNS 5 ROWS AND THAT HAS TO BE STORED IN ONE VARIABLE HOW IT COULD BE CARRIED OUT

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Vpolicyid varchar2(20);

Select t.policyid
Into vpolicyid
From policy to
Where (conditions);
Exception 
When too_many_rows

End;
```

Provided information an exception or too_many_rows is falling.
And each policy I'd will not be greater then 20digits.

How can I store it into that variable.

I am trying to store all the rows of policyid into one variable

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you can't put 5 rows (values) into a scalar variable. But, you can into a collection. For example:

```
declare
  v_policyid sys.odcivarchar2list;
begin
  select t.policyid
    bulk collect into v_policyid
    from policy t
    where conditions;
end;
/
```